# IFrame with PDF embed working in Chrome, but not in IE11

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, internet-explorer, iframe

I have the following code:

```
var pdfWindow = window.open();
pdfWindow.document.write('<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,BASE64STRING" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
```

This is working correctly in Google Chrome, but in IE11 is displaying a blank page.

Is there any way to make it work in IE or there is another alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Internet Explorer does not support the use of DATA URIs as the source of IFRAMEs.

As an alternative workaround, in the IE browser, I suggest you could download the PDF file first, then, using IE browser to display the PDF file.

You could refer to the following code:

```
    function myfunction() {
        var data = "BASE64STRING";
        var fileName = "test.pdf";
        //For IE using atob convert base64 encoded data to byte array
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            var byteCharacters = window.atob(data);
            var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {
            // Directly use base 64 encoded data for rest browsers (not IE)
            var base64EncodedPDF = data;
            var pdfWindow = window.open();
            pdfWindow.document.write('<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64EncodedPDF+'" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the suggestion!